# Handle back button android (onBackPressed)

Tags: android, back, handle

i want to create simple android aplication to streaming video where url get from QR
this is my app flow : scanner - get url - streaming video

but if user press back button 
i wanna it become like this :
1. if app already had url / streaming video already begin, when user press back button....app back scan QR image state again
2. if app still in scanner state, when user press back button app do default android process when app get button back pressed (moveToBack or close)

i try with this code, but no luck

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (flagGetScanningResult) {
        flagGetScanningResult = false;
        launchScanner();
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: put each part of your process in a different fragment and make it through Fragment transactions, that's the recommended way. Do not handle the back press.

Comment: @Budius can you give me example or maybe tutorial link to do it rightway? i have no idea how to do it honestly

Comment: try google.com "android fragment transaction tutorial" there's LOADs of it. Probably start in developer.android.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (flagGetScanningResult) {
        flagGetScanningResult = false;
        launchScanner();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to call the `super` if you are trying to prevent the `Activity` from being destroyed.

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (flagGetScanningResult) {
        flagGetScanningResult = false;
        launchScanner();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
 }
```

Calling through to `super.onBackPressed()` will cause the app to perform it's default 'back' action.

Comment: yeah you're right after i remove super it's work like charm
thanks for detail information :D